# PHP & Laravel: Combining both syntaxes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have been assigned to an existing project which uses PHP, Laravel (5.5) and MySQL. Looking at the exiting code, I noticed that a blade template has both PHP and Laravel syntax.

For example,

```
if(!empty(lines)) {
   // do something
} else {
   // do this
}

@if($someVar)
  //execute this
@endif
```

Is this considered a bad practice? Or is there a reason why one would combine the 2 syntaxes?

Comment: I wouldn't say it was a _bad_ practice, but if this is all happening in the blade templates, then it's an _odd_ practice. Most of the time I would prefer to default to the template syntax, unless there is absolutely something that **_needs_** php logic behind it.

Comment: No, there's no reason, the Blade is compiled to PHP eventually. It was probably just a developer having a forgetful moment.

Comment: That's fine as long as the code is good, however blade allow to use any of the php code with the use of @ php @ endphp so that's fine as long as the code is readable and secure.

Answer (score 0):

The blade template system codes are returned php codes when you change the blade file. Also server only can execute the php file.

the reason for using a different syntax is the convenience.

For example

```
@extends
@yield
@include
```

Also foreach, if, for etc..

Blade (3 lines)

```
@if($var)
    //do something
@endif
```

PHP (5 lines)

```
<?php
if($var) {
    //do something
}
?>
```

Comment: @if is more comparable to the PHP alternative syntax.  `<?php if($var): ?>` `<?php endif; ?>` still 3 lines.

Comment: but there are more letters than blade :). if you use blade, for example: you don't have to write php tags.

Comment: Right, but it has nothing to do with number of lines as your answer indicates.  The php and blade syntax you used aren't very comparable.

Comment: `@extends, @yield, @include` these commands can be define in php as in laravel. But if you use the laravel blade template engine system you don't have to define them. `@if @for` These commands are less challenging than normal PHP commands. You use both less lines and more easily write the view file. This means convenience.